# jquery ajax with cakephp: change event is firing but dropdown box is not getting populated

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, onchange

The following jquery ajax code works fine for the #MerryParentEmail keyup event but it is not working for the #MerryParentState change event. The change event is firing but the city dropdown box is not getting populated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#MerryParentStateId").change(function(){
        state=$(this).val();
        txt_str="state_id="+state;
        $.get("../students/getcities",txt_str,function(result){
            $("#MerryParentCityId").html(result);
        });
     });

 });

</script>
```

students_controller.php

```
   function getcities(){
    $options = $this->Student->MerryParent->City->getCities($this->data['MerryParent']['state_id']);
    print_r($options);
    foreach ($options as $k=>$v){
        echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
    }

}
```

add.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash();

echo $this->Form->create('Student');
echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Student Information</legend>';
echo $this->Form->input('Student.name');

$options = array('Male'=>'Male','Female'=>'Female');
$attributes = array('value'=>'Male');
echo $this->Form->radio('Student.gender',$options,$attributes);

echo $this->Form->input('Student.dob', array('label'=>'Date of Birth',
                'dateFormat'=>'DMY', 
                'empty'=>'Choose one',
                'timeFormat' => '', 
            'minYear' => ( 
                    date('Y') - 5 
            ), 
            'maxYear' => ( 
                    date('Y') - 2 
            ) 
            ));
echo $this->Form->input('Student.merry_class_id', 
        array(
        'label'=>'Enquiry Class for',
        'empty'=>'Choose one',
        'options'=>array('1'=>'Playgroup','2'=>'Nursery','3'=>'LKG', '4'=>'UKG')
        )
        );

echo '</fieldset>';

echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Parent Information</legend>';
//echo $form->input('Student.parent_id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.initial', 
array('empty'=>'Choose one',
'options'=>array('Dr'=>'Dr', 
                'Mr'=>'Mr', 
                'Mrs'=>'Mrs', 
                'Ms'=>'Ms')
)
);
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.email');
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.name', array('label'=>'Parent/Guardian Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.landline');
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.mobile');
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.address');
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.state_id', array('empty'=>'Choose one','options'=>$states));
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.city_id');
echo $this->Form->input('MerryParent.postal_code');
echo '</fieldset>';

echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
 ?>
```

Comment: Is the change event inside document ready? It's possible the change event can't register because the DOM is not yet ready.

Comment: It's not very clear where your PHP ends and your JavaScript begins. Consider editing your question to fix your code. Also, be sure to try running that change event inside the document ready.

Comment: Yes, change event is within document ready. My jquery code is in the layout page default.ctp's head section.

Comment: Ok, now I've added the html form code add.ctp. This is a view in cakePHP. Is that what you are asking for jmort253?

Comment: Where is the HTML element for this:  `$("#MerryParentState")`? Basically, you may want to look into jQuery's live? I have a sneaking suspicion that you're registering the change event before that HTML is rendered. At this point, I can only guess, especially since you're leaving out the most important part of your question, the HTML that your broken change event is referring to. There must be an element on your page somewhere with the id="MerryParentState"? Where is it? It's mia.

Comment: jmort253, i have modified the code now, i have changed to $("#MerryParentStateId") as in the browser's view source. The change event is firing now but the city dropdown box is not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

When I modify getcities function in students_controller.php to include

```
$this->data['MerryParent']['state_id']=$_GET['state_id'];
```

The city dropdown box is getting populated with the cities for the selected state.

So, following is the modified getcities function:

```
function getcities(){
    $this->data['MerryParent']['state_id']=$_GET['state_id'];
    if (!empty($this->data['MerryParent']['state_id'])){
       $cities = $this->Student->MerryParent->City->getCities($this->data['MerryParent']['state_id']);
    //print_r($cities);
    foreach ($cities as $k=>$v){
        echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
    }

        /* foreach($cities as $optionValue){
            echo '<option>' . $optionValue . '</option>';
        }*/
    }else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('You didn\'t select a state!');
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatosDinamicos(){
$id_a = $_GET['agente_id'];
if(!empty($id_a)){
    $listaFormato = $FormatoController->listaVariableFormatoDependent($id_a);
    foreach ($listaFormato as $k=>$v){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>'; 
    }
}else{
    $this->Session->setFlash('Error!');
}
$this->autoRender = false;
}
```

In the button of the function autoRender in false